# C++ - structs... function parameter issue

Tags: c++, struct

At: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/82-classes-and-class-members/

It has the following code:

```
// Declare a DateStruct variable
DateStruct sToday;

// Initialize it manually
sToday.nMonth = 10;
sToday.nDay = 14;
sToday.nYear = 2020;

// Here is a function to initialize a date
void SetDate(DateStruct &sDate, int nMonth, int nDay, int Year)
{
    sDate.nMonth = nMonth;
    sDate.nDay = nDay;
    sDate.nYear = nYear;
}

// Init our date to the same date using the function
SetDate(sToday, 10, 14, 2020);
```

What is the purpose of the

> DateStruct &sDate

parameter in the function signature, especially that I cannot see a use of it in the function body?

Thanks.

Comment: Please please please **read a BOOK**.

Comment: This was written in another place in the articel: "...we needed to pass the struct itself to the SetDate() function as the first parameter. Otherwise, SetDate() wouldn’t know what DateStruct we wanted to work on.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it will take as a first argument a reference to a DateStruct and that this reference will be called sDate in the function's body.
The sDate reference is then used in each lines of the body:

```
sDate.nMonth = nMonth;
sDate.nDay = nDay;
sDate.nYear = nYear;
```

Answer (score 3):

It means a reference to an existing DateStruct instance.

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned, highlighted code is called [a reference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references). You might think of references as aliases for variables.

During function call `sDate` becomes an alias to `sToday` - which has been given as a parameter. Thus it makes it possible to **modify** `sToday` from within the function!

The reason is that it makes possible to give complex structures that might be filled up with data, modified, etc. inside of called functions.

In your case the `SetDate` function takes separate year, month and day - and packs it *inside* `sDate` (== `sToday`) structure.

Just compare the first way of initialization (you need to mention all struct members yourself) to calling `SetDate` function.

eg.:

```
DateStruct janFirst;
DateStruct decLast;

SetDate(janFirst, 1, 1, 2011);
SetDate(decLast, 12, 31, 2011);
```

Compare this to how much code would have been written if you had to fill all those `janFirst`, `decLast` structures by hand!